# Pebble: How to pass an integer as callback_data with app_timer_register?

Tags: c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

Summary of answer:
app_timer_register passes a pointer without type.
To pass an integer, create an integer and pass it's pointer.
Then type the pointer to integer.

example of using the untyped pointer:

```
static void timeHandler(void * untyped_pointer_to_an_integer){
  function_requiring_integer((int)untyped_pointer_to_an_intergger);
```

I'm trying to pass an integer along with the code called by app_time_register.
When I try the following:

```
static void time_handler(int val){ 
  app_timer_register(wait_time_ms, time_handler, 1);
  do_stuff(); 
}
```

I get the error:

```
../src/main.c:88:3: error: passing argument 2 of 'app_timer_register' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
In file included from ../src/main.c:1:0:
/app/sdk3/pebble/chalk/include/pebble.h:2656:11: note: expected 'AppTimerCallback' but argument is of type 'void (*)(int)'
../src/main.c:88:3: error: passing argument 3 of 'app_timer_register' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Werror]
In file included from ../src/main.c:1:0:
/app/sdk3/pebble/chalk/include/pebble.h:2656:11: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'int'
```

Pebble provides the following information about app_time_register (source https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Foundation/Timer/).

```
AppTimer * app_timer_register(uint32_t timeout_ms, AppTimerCallback callback, void * callback_data)
  Registers a timer that ends up in callback being called some specified time in the future.
  Parameters
    timeout_ms
      The expiry time in milliseconds from the current time
    callback
      The callback that gets called at expiry time
    callback_data
      The data that will be passed to callback

typedef void(* AppTimerCallback)(void *data)
The type of function which can be called when a timer fires. The argument will be the callback_data passed to app_timer_register().
```

I need helping figuring out how to use the callback_data to pass an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Figure out what's wrong

Well, both the documentation and the error is very explicit: `app_timer_register` has the signature:

```
AppTimer * app_timer_register(uint32_t, AppTimerCallback, void *);
```

Thus, when calling it, you need to pass an `uint32_t` as first, an `AppTimerCallback` as second and a pointer to void (`void *`) as third argument.

You call it with ...

```
app_timer_register(wait_time_ms, time_handler, 1);
```

... a `wait_time_ms` (which is apparently fine), a pointer to the function `time_handler` (which is of type `void (*)(int)`) and an integer (which your compiler - rightfully - does not want to convert to a `void *` pointer).

Looking up the documentation, `AppTimerCallback` is basically a typedef for a (pointer to) function taking a void pointer as single argument, or more explicit: `void (*)(void *)`

As you see, the types of argument 2 (`void (*)(int)` vs the expected `void (*)(void *)`) and argument 3 (`int` vs the expected `void *`) do not match.

---

### Think about how it needs to be changed and why

The reason to have `void *` as third argument (and as argument for the callback function) is to be able to pass arbitrary data to the callback function (as a `void *` can point to everything).

*This is a idiom often found in C APIs that provide callbacks, it covers up the lack of closures of the language.*

That arbitrary data is most often packed up in a structure (though a single integer - like in your case - could also be "smuggled" as pointer, but this is not scale-able and more over implementation defined):

```
struct time_handler_data {
  int val; // oh my ... we know it's a "value" ... make it more descriptive!
};
```

Thus, your callback needs to look something like ...

```
void time_handler(void * passed) {
  struct time_handler_data * data = passed;
  // ... do stuff with data->val
}
```

... and when you register the callback, you need to actually provide memory for such a structure:

```
struct time_handler_data * data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
// data->val = a fancy value to be used in time_handler
// also check if data != NULL!
AppTimer * you_certainly_need_this =
  app_timer_register(what_ever, &time_handler, data);
// DO NOT FORGET TO free(data) WHEN YOU UNREGISTER THE CALLBACK!
```

Note that using heap allocated memory is of course not mandatory, you could also use memory with static ("globals") or automatic ("stack") storage.

---

### Finally

Registering a callback *inside* the callback itself is probably (I haven't looked into the documentation) not the way it's intended to be. Normally it's more like ...

```
void /* or not */ register_time_handler(/* fancy arguments */)
{
   // code calling app_timer_register from above
}
```

... and having no call to `app_timer_register` in the actual callback (`time_handler`).

Comment: Thank you for providing some C programming advice along with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that `void (*)(int)` is incompatible with `void(*)(void *data)`.

Instead, have the parameter be of the appropriate type:

```
static void time_handler(void *val) { 
  app_timer_register(wait_time_ms, time_handler, 1);
  do_stuff(); 
}
```

If you need to pass an integer into `time_handler`, allocate space for it and pass the pointer. Casting an integer to `void*` and back is also possible, but it's implementation-defined behavior whether it works. It works on ARM (ARM ABI specifies `sizeof (int) == sizeof(void*) && _Alignof(int) == _Alignof(void*)`).